# Importing seaborn in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

I have upgraded `seaborn` to `0.9.0` and `pycharm` seems to be unimpressed.

A script *that works on the command line* is unable to proceed past:

```
 import seaborn as sns
```

The following is thrown:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in main
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, in run
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "/Applications/PyCharm CE.app/Contents/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "/git/uni/_psl/proj1/myMain.py", line 202, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from .widgets import *
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/seaborn/widgets.py", line 8, in <module>
    from ipywidgets import interact, FloatSlider, IntSlider
  File "/Users/sboesch/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/ipywidgets/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from IPython import get_ipython
  File "/Users/sboesch/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/__init__.py", line 54, in <module>
    from .core.application import Application
  File "/Users/sboesch/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py", line 25, in <module>
    from IPython.core import release, crashhandler
  File "/Users/sboesch/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/core/crashhandler.py", line 27, in <module>
    from IPython.core import ultratb
  File "/Users/sboesch/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/core/ultratb.py", line 115, in <module>
    from IPython.core import debugger
  File "/Users/sboesch/Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages/IPython/core/debugger.py", line 46, in <module>
    from pdb import Pdb as OldPdb
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.4_4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/pdb.py", line 136, in <module>
    class Pdb(bdb.Bdb, cmd.Cmd):
AttributeError: module 'cmd' has no attribute 'Cmd'
```

Any tips appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a custom module/package `cmd` in your project? It can be a `PYTHONPATH` collision.

Comment: oh! there's a `cmd.py`  in an old old folder in an entirely different part of the project. Looks like `Intellij` "found" that old folder. I did not realize IJ would go find all of the folders in the entire project and add them to the `PYTHONPATH`. Please make an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen due to `PYTHONPATH` collision in case you have a custom module/package with the same name as a standard library module/package, e.g. `cmd`.

The trick is PyCharm and IntelliJ with Python plugin add project root, content roots and source roots to `PYTHONPATH` so the script may work correctly in the terminal but fail when executed in the IDE.

To disable this behavior for content and source roots go to the dedicated run configuration and uncheck options

- Add content roots to PYTHONPATH
- Add source roots to PYTHONPATH

or right-click on the corresponding directory in the project tree **-> Mark Directory as -> Unmark as Sources Root**.

Content roots can be managed in **Settings | Project ... | Project Structure**.